# Is it possible to estimate the elipse perimeter using linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Assuming the elipse is just an circle being stretch on one aix, And the perimeter of shape equals to the sum of all Vectors length. We may say that the elipse is an circle being linearly transform to an elipse and then the change in the perimeter is the basically change in all vectors length which we can calculate by divide the transformation into very small transformations each of them create elpise  from the last elipse . Till you get the final elipse from the circle . Because  if we take a shape and  will scale one aix of each vector of the shape you will get new shape with perimeter equal to the ratio between all y values of each vector and x value of each vector. But in case of elipse the ratio change as match the ratio betweens the big decimeter of the elipse and the small one , Get bigger. So in this case we may divide it  to multiple transformation each time we multiply perimeter of the last elipse by the ratio between the decimeters of the elipse and the old perimeter. For example if i have an elpise whcih have one decimter of 32 and one of 1 for calculating the perimeter this elipse we first calculate the permiter of circle of decimter 1 which is 2pie then we will calculate the permiter of an elipse which have a value equal to 1 and b value equal to 2 , Assuming a is the short decimter and b is the longer. We would calculate it by saying that in case where we increase one aix of the vectors that created the circle , we actually only scale up the length  50% of the vectors whcih means that the permiter of the new elipse would be 2pie * 0.5*2 ,And then calculate the next elipse whcih  have a value of 1 and b value of 4 in the case the ratio between a and be is 1/4 whcih means 75% of the vectors would have bigger length which means the the permiter of the new elipse would be 3*2*0.75=4.5pie . Doing so till getting the correct elpise giving me prity good results am I wrong about doing so?. Can I use some the constant E instead of calculating all the elipses?

Answer (score 0):

No. This is because if you stretch one dimension by a factor $\alpha$, the curve length *is not proportional* to this stretch. The curve length operator is a *non-linear* operator.

You can clearly see this by measuring the hypotenuse of a triangle

[image: fig1]

and noting that $\sqrt{\alpha^2+1}$ is not proportional to $\alpha$.

Comment: But you can build circle by small parallel lines to the aixes

Comment: "But you can build circle by small parallel lines to the aixes" ... Really? In what sense is that true?